# How to merge/shift rows/columns up or down basis 2048 game

Tags: python, arrays, merge, 2048

I need some help creating 2 functions `push_up` and `push_down` (think 2048 game), I've managed to create functions that would push the values left and right and then sum them together if they are of equal value. For example, `[2,2,0,0]` would return as `[4,0,0,0]`. I have a separate function that adds random numbers.

I need to do the same with up and down, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is my starting array:

```py
grid = [
  [2, 2, 0, 2],
  [0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 4],
  [4, 0, 4, 0]
]
```

And here are my functions:

```py
def push_right(grid):
    for row in grid:
        for i, number in reversed(list(enumerate(row))):
            if number == row[i-1]:
                row[i] = number + row[i-1]
                row[i-1] = 0
        row.sort(key=lambda v: v != 0)

    return grid

def push_left(grid):

    for row in grid:
        for i, number in reversed(list(enumerate(row))):
            if number == row[i-1]:
                row[i] = number + row[i-1]
                row[i-1] = 0
        row.sort(key=lambda v: v != 0, reverse=True)

    return grid

print(push_right(grid))
print(push_left(grid))
```

Which outputs:

```py
[
  [0, 0, 4, 4],
  [0, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 2, 4],
  [0, 0, 4, 4]
]
```

And:

```py
[
  [8, 0, 0, 0],
  [2, 0, 0, 0],
  [2, 4, 0, 0],
  [8, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I have a function which prints this out on a grid, but I need some help to code functions which will shift and merge up and down. For example, for the array:

```py
[
  [0, 0, 4, 4],
  [0, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 2, 4],
  [0, 0, 4, 4]
]
```

Down would be:

```py
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 4, 4],
  [0, 0, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 4, 8]
]
```

And up would be:

```py
[
  [0, 0, 4, 4],
  [0, 0, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 4, 8],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Push right and push left are the same? Order is important on merging. I know you reverse it in the end but that does not make the merging correct?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to coding to it could be an error. I was just looking at what the output was.. Please feel to give me some advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine syntax wise. There are some logic errors you should first fix. Push left and right is not working yet. Take this example

```
[
  [0, 4, 0, 4],
  [0, 0, 0, 2],
  [0, 0, 2, 4],
  [4, 2, 2, 4]
]
```

For right this returns:

```
[
[0, 0, 4, 4], 
[0, 0, 0, 2], 
[0, 0, 2, 4], 
[0, 0, 8, 4]
]
```

For left the same is returned but reversed. Can you see the mistake on the first and last line? You should rethink the logic..

When that is done, you can create columns with a loop. (First take all first numbers of each column, then all second,...)

If you have a list of columns, you can actually use the same logic of pushing left or right.

I will provide more code when needed, I just wanted to give you some advice first :)